# Django 1.5 - Login

Tags: django, django-1.5

After creating a UserProfile model. I started to create login but I'm stuck because of get_user() error.

**EXCEPTION**

```
 AttributeError: 'LoginForm' object has no attribute 'get_user'
```

Here are my codes:

**UPDATE**

```
class LoginView(FormView):
    form_class = LoginForm
    redirect_field_name = REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME
    template_name = 'login.html'
    success_url = '/'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        username = form.cleaned_data['username']
        password = form.cleaned_data['password']

        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                login(self.request, user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
        else:        
            return self.form_invalid()

    def form_invalid(self):
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('accounts:login'))

    def get_success_url(self):
        if self.success_url:
            redirect_to = self.success_url
        else:
            redirect_to = self.request.REQUEST.get(self.redirect_field_name, '')

        netloc = urlparse.urlparse(redirect_to)[1]
        if not redirect_to:
            redirect_to = settings.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL
        elif netloc and netloc != self.request.get_host():
            redirect_to = settings.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL
        return redirect_to

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form_class = self.get_form_class()
        form = self.get_form(form_class)
        if form.is_valid():
            return self.form_valid(form)
        else:                
            return self.form_invalid()
```

How to fix this? Any help would be appreciated. I'm really new on Django 1.5. Need help.

Comment: I found this in the documentation: If you have customized authentication (see Customizing Authentication) you can pass a custom authentication form to the login view via the authentication_form parameter. This form must accept a request keyword argument in its __init__ method, and provide a get_user method which returns the authenticated user object (this method is only ever called after successful form validation).

Comment: Can you post LoginForm's code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[update]

In the original code, the author is doing the `authenticate` stuff inside a form method called `get_user`. You are doing it outside the form already, so just replace `form.get_user()`with `user`.

I use a login view that is not class based, and I don't even care into using a Django form instance, but it should be easy to adapt:

```
def signin(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user = authenticate(
            email=request.POST.get('username', '').lower().strip(),
            password= request.POST.get('password', ''),
        )
        if user is None:
            messages.error(request, u'Invalid credentials')
        else:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect(request.GET.get('next', '/'))
            else:
                messages.error(request, u'User is not active.')

    return render_to_response('login.html', locals(),      
                       context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

[old answer]

Define a get_user method for your form.

Untested (but should get you in the right path):

```
def get_user(self):
    from django.contrib.auth import authenticate
    return authenticate(
            email=self.cleaned_data.get('username', '').lower().strip(),
            password=self.cleaned_data.get('password', ''),
    )
```

Comment: @catherine: could you try the updated code? (I use the email field as username, please adapt to your needs)

Comment: Would you like to move to the chat?

Comment: Error again, 'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute 'backend'

Comment: how there is no shortcut link to move to chat?